# Finding the eigenvectors of a submatrix

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, linear-programming, eigenvector

Let $A=(a_{kl})$ be a matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ when $n$ is even. Let $B=(b_{kl})$ be the ***symmetric*** $2n$ by $2n$ matrix whose entries are given by,

- $b_{k,l}=a_{kl}$ if $1\leq k,l\leq n$.
- $b_{n+k,l}=b_{kl}$ if $l$ is odd.
- $b_{n+k,l}=-b_{kl}$ if $l$ is even.

Q. Let $V$ be a basis for the eigenvectors of $B$. Is there any approach to derive a basis for the eigenvectors of $A$ from $V$?

Comment: I would assume the opposite. If you know the eigenvectors of $A$ then you could try to build eigenvectors for $B$, changing the sign of certain components. With a bit of luck, you could use one eigenvector for $A$ to generate two different eigenvectors for $B$. Anyways, did you try $n=2$ and test some simple cases by hand??

Comment: Yes, extending  eigenvectors of the submatrix $A$ to $B$ would be also considered  as a question. But, the converse process is my concern for now.

Comment: What is $b_{n+k,n+l}$? Also it seems to me that if $A$ isn't symmetric then B won't be neither since the top left $n \times n$ block of $B$ is exactly $A$.

Comment: $B$ is supposed to be symmetric, so to find $B$ we need only to know left side entries that are known for us.

Comment: I don't think you defined the fourth block as $B=\begin{pmatrix}A&AU\\AU&*\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I have done.

Comment: Your notation is also so helpful.

Comment: This is still unclear,  is it $B=\begin{pmatrix}A&AU\\AU&AU\end{pmatrix}$ for a $\pm 1$ diagonal matrix $U$...